# hasMany vs belongsToMany in laravel 5.x

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm curious why the Eloquent relationship for `hasMany` has a different signature than for `belongsToMany`. Specifically the custom join table name-- for a system where a given `Comment` belongs to many `Role`s, and a given `Role` would have many `Comment`s, I want to store the relationship in a table called `my_custom_join_table` and have the keys set up as `comment_key` and `role_key`.

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'my_custom_join_table', 'comment_key', 'role_key'); // works
```

But on the inverse, I can't define that custom table (at least the docs don't mention it):

```
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'comment_key', 'role_key');
```

If I have a `Role` object that `hasMany` `Comments`, but I use a non-standard table name to store that relationship, why can I use this non-standard table going one way but not the other?

Comment: The inverse of a bi-directional many-to-many relationship is many-to-many, not one-to-many. Doctrine has a [nice presentation of all the relation orders](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional) and their implementations.

Comment: The official documentation also has a very nice write up about Eloquent relations https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 277, accepted):

`hasMany` is used in a [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship while `belongsToMany` refers to a [Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship. They are both distinct relationship types and each require a different database structure - thus they take different parameters.

The key difference is that in a One To Many relationship, you only need the two database tables that correspond to the related models. This is because the reference to the relation is *stored on the owned model's table itself*. For instance, you might have a `Country` model and a `City` model. A Country has many cities. However, each City only exists in one country. Therefore, you would store that country *on the City model itself* (as `country_id` or something like that).

However, a Many To Many relationship requires a *third* database table, called a **pivot table**. The pivot table stores references to both the models and you can declare it as a second parameter in the relationship declaration. For example, imagine you have your `City` model and you also have a `Car` model. You want a relationship to show the types of cars people drive in each city. Well, in one city people will drive *many* different types of car. However, if you look at one car type you will also know that it can be driven in *many* different cities. Therefore it would be impossible to store a `city_id` or a `car_id` on either model because each would have more than one. Therefore, you put those references in the pivot table.

As a rule of thumb, if you use a `belongsToMany` relationship, it can *only* be paired with another `belongsToMany` relationship and means that you have a third pivot table. If you use a `hasMany` relationship, it can *only* be paired with a `belongsTo` relationship and no extra database tables are required.

In your example, you just need to make the inverse relation into a `belongsToMany` and add your custom table again, along with the foreign and local keys (reversing the order from the other model).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily say that a *Many To Many* relationship requires three tables. The relation could be between the same model, resulting in only **two** database tables. Example: User Friendship.

Answer (score 62):

Try to understand with text and a figure.

1. One to One(hasOne) relationship:

   - A user has(can have) one profile.  So, a profile belongs to one user.
2. One to many(hasMany):

   - A user has many(can have many) articles. So, many articles belong to one user.
3. Many to many(BelongsToMany):

   - A User can belong to many forums. So, a forum belongs to many users.

   [image: RelationShip]

Comment: In the case of hasOne/belongsTo, I suppose the hasOne dictates which table will hold the reference to the related table (User table has a profile_id in this case)?

Comment: I would also add a "hasMany" and "belongsTo" diagram which is exactly like the first in the diagram. ie a person can have many dogs, and each dog belongs to one owner (extra info, not related to the question)